# how do I import my existing RadRails project into a new SVN repository?

Tags: svn, radrails

I currently have an existing project that I have been working on in RadRails.  I want to put the entire project into an SVN repository (hosted on Unfuddle).  I downloaded the Subversion plugin.

I'm not sure how to actually take this file and commit it into the existing SVN repository.

Comment: What describes a RadRails project? is it a project file, and source files on your local machine?

Comment: yes, I used RadRails new -> Rails project and then developed the app, so it has both the rails framework and my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not really familiar with RadRails. The [FAQ](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/faqs/tools-and-utilities/subversion-svn) says they use Eclipse Subversive for Subversion support. They link to the Subversive manual for advanced topics from that FAQ page.

The way to import it manually (with the commandline client) is probably to first create the repository structure you want, by using (for instance):

```
svn mkdir http://server/svn/repos/trunk
```

Then checkout the empty directory in your project root, so you get a working copy where you can add things:

```
svn checkout http://server/svn/repos/trunk c:\MyProject
```

Then you can add files and directories